# vertx deploy vertical after getting reply from event bus

Tags: java, mysql, vert.x

I want to deploy vertical after getting reply from my event bus which is calling mysql module.

---

```
String query = "select * from fca_config WHERE name='siteFaultCollectionStatus'";
JsonObject selectQuery = new JsonObject();
selectQuery.putString(OPERATION.ACTION.Value(), OPERATION.RAW.Value());
selectQuery.putString(OPERATION.COMMAND.Value(), query);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("siteFaultCollectionStatus");

System.out.println(selectQuery);

EventBus eb = vertx.eventBus();
eb.send("database.mysql", selectQuery, new Handler<Message<JsonObject>>() {
  public void handle(Message<JsonObject> result) {
      String results = result.body().getArray("results").toString();
      String arrs[]=results.split(",");
    System.out.println("I received a reply before the timeout of 5 seconds"+arrs[1]);
    res=arrs[1];
    }
});
if(res.equals("true")){
   deployVerticles();
```

---

After getting reply(true/false) from this i want to deploy module, but before getting reply from this my vertical is getting deployed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include your deployment method within the body of the response handler so that it gets called once the event bus has sent the message, received a response and inspected the response message body:

```java
// ...
JsonObject selectQuery /* the query initialization goes here */;
// ...
vertx.eventBus().send(
  "database.mysql", 
  selectQuery, 
  new Handler<Message<JsonObject>>() {
    public void handle(Message<JsonObject> result) {
      String results = result.body().getArray("results").toString();
      String arrs[]=results.split(",");
      System.out.println("I received a reply before the timeout of 5 seconds"+arrs[1]);
      res = arrs[1];
      if(res.equals("true")) {
        deployVerticles(); // Triggering verticle deployment goes within your response handler
      }
    }
  }
);
```